# How to import files from the test folder in a Haskell-Stack project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using stack and my Haskell project has the standard shape:

```
.
├── app
│   └── Main.hs
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Setup.hs
├── src
│   ├── Lib.hs
│   └── ...
├── stack.yaml
├── package.yaml
├── test
│   └── Suit1.hs
│   └── Suit2.hs
│   └── TestUtility.hs
└── MyProject.cabal
```

I have two test suits `Suit1` and `Suit2` whcih share a common code in `TestUtility`. However I'm failing to import this common code!

`import TestUtility`

Fails with `Could not find module ‘TestUtility’`. Looking at the verbose output of GHC, I can tell that it's only looking at the `src` and `app` folders for modules. How do I tell it to look at the `test` folder?

In my `package.yaml` I'm using the following:

```
tests:
 suite1:
    main:                Suite1.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:         
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    - -main-is Suite1
    other-modules:
    - TestUtility.hs ## Doesn't seem to be doing anything
    dependencies:
    - acme-missiles
```

So my main question is, what do I need to add so that GHC sees other files in the test directory but only for test suits (don't want to export that in the library)?

Secondary question, is why is GHC lookin in the app folder? Is that default behavior, or is is derived from where the executables are?

Comment: Looking at one of my `package.yaml` files that work, the only difference that jumps out is that mine has no `other-modules` section. I think it's supposed to just pick up all the files in your `test` folder. Have you tried to remove the `other-modules` section?

Comment: Where is the `Programs.Programs`? I'm wondering if the build error is coming at a different stage than compiling tests?

Comment: Removing `other-modules` has no effect. It's not looking for files in the `test` folder.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. `Programs.Programs` should have been `TestUtility`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you have a typo in [*suite*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/test_suite#English)